# How to use Charles proxy web interface?

Tags: charles-proxy

In Charles proxy unable to start/stop recording using web interface. I have enabled the web interface and transparent ssl proxy option. I am able to navigate one level from the home page http://control.charles/ like http://control.charles/recording/ . However, I'm not able to access anything further like http://control.charles/recording/start

It is giving HTTP 404 error message in the browser response. Same thing I tried using curl and found that Charles proxy is throwing out of memory error. I have increased the -Xmx to 2GB in info.plist file and still facing the same.

```
Exception in thread "com.xk72.proxy.ssl.vTMQ.LajB" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
unable to create new native thread at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) at 
java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378) at 
com.xk72.proxy.sJmZ.wIxc.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) SEVERE 
com.xk72.proxy.server.SocketProxyServer SocketProxyServer.run 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread at 
java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378) at 
com.xk72.util.LajB.DdNM(Unknown Source) at com.xk72.throttle.AqRW.(Unknown Source) 
at com.xk72.throttle.WSQr.getInputStream(Unknown Source) at 
com.xk72.proxy.http.wDPH.DdNM(Unknown Source) at 
com.xk72.proxy.http.CLFr.twLa(Unknown Source) at 
com.xk72.proxy.http.CLFr.DdNM(Unknown Source) at 
com.xk72.proxy.http.CLFr.DdNM(Unknown Source) at 
com.xk72.proxy.sJmZ.wDPH.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Details: Mac High Sierra - 10.13.6 Jre - 1.8.163 Charles - 4.2.8

Comment: I tested in Charles v4.2.8 on Mac Sierra 10.12.6 (JRE 1.8.0_05), this problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @shaochuancs , is it possible to check in JRE 1.8.163 ?